# How to change the CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to Convert_Year_to_Year into Day_to_Day

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The following code returns the Year an employee was born:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Convert_Year_to_Year (Convert_Date IN Date)
       RETURN Varchar2 AS
BEGIN
       RETURN (To_Char (Convert_Date, ‘YEAR’));
END;
/
```

When I use the SELECT command to retrieve the data, the following output displays:

```
Select employee_id, hiredate,  Convert_year_to_year (hiredate) AS Year_Hired 
FROM employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID HIREDATE    YEAR_HIRED
       1    12/17/2007  TWO THOUSAND SEVEN
       2    02/20/2008  TWO THOUSAND EIGHT
       3    02/22/2008  TWO THOUSAND EIGHT
       4    04/02/2008  TWO THOUSAND EIGHT
       5    09/28/2008  TWO THOUSAND EIGHT
       6    05/01/2008  TWO THOUSAND EIGHT
       7    06/09/2008  TWO THOUSAND EIGHT
       8    12/09/2008  TWO THOUSAND EIGHT
       9    09/08/2007  TWO THOUSAND SEVEN
      10    01/12/2007  TWO THOUSAND SEVEN
```

1. How can I change the "YEAR_HIRED" to numeric year for example 2007?
2. How can I change the "YEAR_HIRED" to return the name of the day along with the day of the week?

> ADDITIONALLY, if I want to combine all the RETURNs, how can I write the code? Below didn't work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Convert_Year_to_Year (Convert_Date IN Date)
     RETURN Varchar2 AS
BEGIN
     RETURN (To_Char (Convert_Date, 'YYYY'),
     RETURN (To_Char (Convert_Date, 'DAY'),
     RETURN (To_Char (Convert_Date, 'D'));
END;
/

EMPLOYEE_ID HIREDATE    YEAR_HIRED DAY_HIRED  NUMERICAL_DAY_OF_WEEK
       1    12/17/2007  2007       MONDAY      1
       2    02/20/2008  2008       WEDNESDAY   3
       3    02/22/2008  2008       FRIDAY      5
       4    04/02/2008  2008       WEDNESDAY   5
       5    09/28/2008  2008       SUNDAY      7
```

Comment: What's the difference between `name of the day` and `day of the week`?

Comment: Do you want to return 3 separate values (you'll want 3 separate functions)?  Or do you want 1 big return value will the 3 bits of information concatenated together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the numeric year (e.g. `2007`):

```
TO_CHAR(Convert_Date, 'YYYY')
```

To get the name of the day of the week (e.g. `SATURDAY`) :

```
TO_CHAR(Convert_Date, 'DAY')
```

To get the numerical value of the day of the week (e.g. `7`):

```
TO_CHAR(Convert_Date, 'D')
```

And if you really to get the numerical values of the week in a non-standard way (e.g. Monday = 1, ... Saturday = 6, Sunday = 7), then this ugliness will do the job:

```
to_char(decode(to_number(to_char(Convert_Date, 'D')) - 1, 0, 7, to_number(to_char(Convert_Date, 'D')) - 1))
```

**EDIT**

To return the 3 bits of information as 3 separate columns of your query, you need to create 3 separate functions, or, simply write this query without the function, which isn't doing much for you anyways (but you cannot have 3 `return` statements in your function):

```
Select employee_id, 
       hiredate,  
       TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'YYYY') AS Year_Hired,
       TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DAY') AS DAY_HIRED,
       decode(to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'D')) - 1, 0, 7, to_number(to_char(hiredate, 'D')) - 1) AS NUMERICAL_DAY_OF_WEEK
FROM employees;
```

Comment: name of the day refers to (e.g. SUNDAY), and day of the week refers to (e.g. 5 for Friday and 7 for Sunday)

Comment: I edited my post.  But the built-in function to get the numerical value of the day of the week is `Sunday` = `1` ... `Saturday` = `7`.  Do you really need it to be numbered in a non-standard way?

Comment: Is it possible though, to have it in a non-standard way?

Comment: Also, how can I put all the conversion so that it displace the year, day, and the numerical value of the day of the week?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `displace`?  If it's not simple to explain in words, please edit your post with examples.

Comment: Both ways worked perfectly. Thank you once again. I envy the amount of knowledge you have.